# How to delete all rows from a table except newest 10 rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Mysql schema of result `(str)`, created `(timestamp, current on create)` and I would like to run a query to delete all except the last 10, how would I do that?

Answer (score 8):

```
  DELETE FROM tablename 
    WHERE id NOT IN (
      SELECT id FROM tablename 
      ORDER BY created DESC 
      LIMIT 10);
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do it with join? Says mysql version doesn't support limit in "in"

Comment: There is a way to do it using a self referencing left join... I'm just not sure of the syntax at the moment.

Comment: This style of `DELETE` is quite dangerous for two reasons: Reason1) The Query Optimizer tends to barf at `DELETE`-based/`UPDATE`-based self-referencing joins ( I wrote about this in the DBA StackExchange : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1384/877 ), Reason2) In MySQL Replication, there is no guarantee of row order. Thus, the last 10 rows might be different on a Slave than from that of its Master.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Good information to know... I wasn't sure enough to throw out something given this is a destructive operation. Would grabbing the count on the table and runing an ordered delete limited to count -10 work in this case?

Comment: can't update/delete a tablethat you're selecting from anyways. This will fail in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You should collect the 10 ids first

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ids_to_keep ENGINE=MyISAM
SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE 1=2;
INSERT INTO ids_to_keep
SELECT id FROM tablename ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10
ALTER TABLE ids_to_keep ADD PRIMARY KEYS (id);
```

From there, try one of these two techniques:

## TECHNIQUE #1 : DELETE JOIN

```
DELETE A.* FROM tablename A
LEFT JOIN ids_to_keep B USING (id)
WHERE B.id IS NULL;
DROP TABLE ids_to_keep;
```

## TECHNIQUE #2 : TABLE RECREATION

```
CREATE TABLE tablename_new LIKE tablename;
ALTER TABLE tablename RENAME tablename_org;
INSERT INTO tablename_new
SELECT A.* FROM tablename_org A INNER JOIN ids_to_keep B USING (id);
DROP TABLE tablename_org;
ALTER TABLE tablename_new RENAME tablename;
DROP TABLE ids_to_keep;
```

## Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a variant of a method for finding the Nth maximum value in a table using a self join.

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE created < (
SELECT created FROM tablename t1 WHERE
 (N - 1) = (SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT( created )
            FROM tablename t1
            WHERE t2.created > t1.created ) ) )
```

The interior part of the query gives you the Nth largest value of "created" from your table, which you can use as a reference to delete everything that came earlier.

Comment: `MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM lastten t1 WHERE t2.created > t1.created ) ) )' at line 4`

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is 9 rows, not 10, but you get the idea...

```
SELECT * FROM created;
+---------------------+
| t                   |
+---------------------+
| 2013-05-28 19:17:03 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:06 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:09 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:11 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:13 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:16 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:17 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:19 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:21 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:23 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:25 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:27 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:29 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:31 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:33 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:35 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:37 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:39 |
+---------------------+
18 rows in set (0.00 sec)

DELETE a
  FROM created a
  JOIN
     (  SELECT x.*
          FROM created x
          JOIN created y
            ON y.t >= x.t
         GROUP
            BY x.t
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 10
     ) b
    ON b.t >= a.t;

SELECT * FROM created;
+---------------------+
| t                   |
+---------------------+
| 2013-05-28 19:17:23 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:25 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:27 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:29 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:31 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:33 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:35 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:37 |
| 2013-05-28 19:17:39 |
+---------------------+
```