# Mysql delete all except 100 new rows

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I need to empty all table except the x new rows i have already test

[How to delete all rows from a table except newest 10 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797682/how-to-delete-all-rows-from-a-table-except-newest-10-rows)

[SQL Delete all rows except for last 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206009/sql-delete-all-rows-except-for-last-100)

But not work, my mysql version doesn't support limit "IN"
(actual version  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.46)

My table is like that

```
ID (int)
DATE (timestamp)
```

Who i can empty without loop ? Thanks

Comment: would you like to do it from `php` or from `mysql`?

Comment: What error do you get when you use `DELETE` statement with `IN` operator?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos i have 'This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a single SQL `DELETE` statement that uses variables:

```sql
DELETE mytable
FROM mytable 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ID, @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) AS var
  ORDER BY DATE DESC
) AS t ON mytable.ID = t.ID
AND t.rn > 100
```

The derived tasble `t` is used to assign each `ID` of `mytable` a row number. Numbering uses `ORDER BY DATE DESC`, hence 100 most recent records are going to have `rn` in [1-100]. `DELETE` removes any row of `mytable` except those having `rn` in [1-100].

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c1d7/2) (Demo keeps 10 more recent records instead of 100)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<?php
$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db");
$result=$mysqli->query("select id from tabl order by id desc" );
$res=$result->fetch_array();
echo $res[0];
$id=$res[0]-100;
$mysqli->query("delete from table where id < $id");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using number of SQL statments one after another.

You can do it by get the first `ID` that you want to delete, and then delete all the rows newer that `ID`

```
// Create the memory table for storing the IDs
create table mem(
   first100 integer
);

// Insert to the memory table the list of 100 last ids
insert into mem(first100) select id from table order by id desc limit 100;

// Insert to Mysql variable @a, the id of the first id  to delete
set @a=select fist100 from mem order by id limit 1;

// Delete all the id's after the one you want to delete
delete from table where id>=@a
```

**Update:**
I posted this answer befor you wroted that the error message is: `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME`

Anyway, I keep it, maybe this method will help to someone else .